# How can I use Perl to send and HTTP request with a cookie?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I want to write a Perl program that:

- creates an HTTP request
- sends it to any URL (e.g. http://www.google.com )
- includes a cookie in the request
- logs the http response codes in a file

I have tried this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
require HTTP::Request;
require LWP::UserAgent;

$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.google.com/');
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->cookie_jar({file => "testcookies.txt",autosave =>1});

$response = $ua->request($request);
if($response->is_success){
print "sucess\n";
print $response->code;
}
else {
print "fail\n";
die $response->code;
}
```

pls tell how to set cookie in 'request' ie

how to set a cookie when we send HTTP::Request

i was expecting something like:

```
$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.google.com/');
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->new CGI::Cookie(-name=>"myCookie",-value=>"fghij");
```

is this possible??

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? What are you getting stuck on? I'm also not sure how Putty/finesse relate to your question.

Comment: Cookies are stored in the client side. Maybe you want to send cookie values but not the cookie itself.

Comment: +1 `pls tell how to set cookie in 'request'` is an error message I have never seen before - not even in Perl :)

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode:  oops! forgot to add 'Error Message' their ..solved it anyways
Question is edited.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned cookies are in HTTP::Cookies:

- You need to create a cookie jar
- You set the value of the cookies to put in the jar
- You then associate that jar with your user agent

For example:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookies->set_cookie(0,'cookiename', 'value','/','google.com',80,0,0,86400,0);
$ua->cookie_jar($cookies);
# Now make your request
```

`set_cookie` has a rather large number of arguments:

> set_cookie( $version, $key, $val, $path, $domain, $port,
>          $path_spec, $secure, $maxage, $discard, \%rest )

This is because the cookie jar is designed from the point of view of a browser (a UserAgent), rather than a single request. This means not all the arguments are so important in this case.

The ones you need to get right are $key, $val, $path, $domain, $port.

Regarding the:

> 500 Can't connect to www.google.com:80
>   (Bad hostname 'www.google.com')

It means that LWP can't lookup the address for Google. Are you behind a web proxy? If so you will need to set your proxy in the UA too using something like:

$ua->proxy(['http', 'https'], 'http://proxyhost.my.domain.com:8080/');

Comment: what does 
$cookies->set_cookie(0,'cookiename', 'value','/','google.com',80,0,0,86400,0);  statement do can you please  explain in detail

Comment: added detail on set_cookie - for even more info look at the HTTP::Cookie man page, or Wikipedia's HTTP Cookie page.

Answer (score 3):

Start with [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent) and [HTTP::Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Cookies)

Comment: LWP::UserAgent shows for HTTP response  i want simple http request with set cookie

Comment: How do you expect to record the status code without looking at the response?

Comment: i had no clue ,thanks anyways...


and what about 'logging the http response codes in a file'

Comment: @dexter: The simple way: Open a file and print the response codes into it.  The powerful way: Use Log4perl (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log::Log4perl).

Comment: edited using Link by David and
http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/libwww-perl/HTTP/Request.html#NAME