# How can I log the HTTP response codes in the file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

I have created HTTP::Request which looks like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
require HTTP::Request;
require LWP::UserAgent;
require HTTP::Cookies;

$request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.google.com/');
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$ua->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);
$cookie_jar->set_cookie(0,'testCookie','cookieValue','/','http://www.google.com/',80,0,0,86400,0);

$response = $ua->request($request);
if($response->is_success){
print "sucess\n";
print $response->code;
print "\n";
}
else {
print "fail\n";
die $response->code;
print "\n";
}
```

now, When i send Request:
i want to  **log the http response codes in the  file**

please help
thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475362/how-can-i-use-perl-to-send-and-http-request-with-a-cookie

Comment: @David Dorward: this could have been a different question but joined in the question you provided.
No detailed answer was given so i separated this one to get specific answer hope you'll understand

Comment: See that **`$response->code;`** Well, instead of dying, go log that where ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print to a file, then print to a file:

```
 open my($log), '>', $log_file or die "Could not open $log_file: $!";

 ....

 if($response->is_success){
     print $log "success:", $response->code, "\n";
 }
 else {
     print $log "fail: ", $response->code, "\n";
 }
```

The general way to solve these sorts of issues is figure out what you want to do then find out how to do that by looking in the docs or a Perl tutorial. Most of the things you will ever want to do will be just combining the basics you'll find in [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113).

Comment: when i used above code gave me following message :
Could Not open $log file do i need to create the file somewhere can you please elaborate more

Comment: As I said in the last sentence, you probably want to go through _Learning Perl_.