# How to make HTTP request with cookie

Tags: perl, http

I am trying to send a simple HTTP GET request to a server at `http://server/?id=` containing a cookie. I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475362/how-can-i-use-perl-to-send-and-http-request-with-a-cookie) which should answer my question. But the following code errs with

> Can't connect to server:443 (certificate verify failed)

Which is odd as I never requested to use https.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require HTTP::Request;
require HTTP::Cookies;
require HTTP::Message;
require HTTP::Response;
require HTTP::Headers;
require LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookies->set_cookie(0,'sid','/','server');
$ua->cookie_jar( $cookies );
$response = $ua->get( 'http://server/?id=user' );
print $response->content();
```

Comment: Presumably, the server is redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS.

Comment: so perl is doing the redirect for me without notifying me?

Comment: [The request() method will process redirects and authentication responses transparently.](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-request-request)

Comment: @Quentin ah great, that explains a lot. I'd accept this as an answer (I verified it and the server really does a redirect - i never noticed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the server is redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS.
[The request() method will process redirects and authentication responses transparently.](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-request-request)
 – Quentin